# php regex - replace on "\${1}"

Tags: php, regex

found this regex:

```
insert " " every 10 characters:  
$text =  preg_replace("|(.{10})|u", "\${1}"." ", $text);
```

can you, please, explain what `\${1}` means. Why using `\` and what curly brackets means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting some portions of the manual page of **[`preg_replace`](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace)** :

> `replacement` may contain references of
>   the form `\\n` or **`$n`, with the latter
>   form being the preferred one**.

You are, apparently, in the second case : `$n`

And, later :

> When working with a replacement
>   pattern where a backreference is
>   immediately followed by another number
>   *(i.e.: placing a literal number
>   immediately after a matched pattern)*,
>   you cannot use the familiar `\\1`
>   notation for your backreference.
>   
> `\\11`, for example, would confuse
>   `preg_replace()` since it does not know
>   whether you want the `\\1` backreference
>   followed by a literal `1`, or the `\\11`
>   backreference followed by nothing.
>   
> **In this case the solution is to
>   use `\${1}1`**. This creates an isolated
>   `$1` backreference, leaving the `1` as a
>   literal.

Here, you don't have anything after what would be `$1` -- but I suppose it cannot hurt to use the `\${1}` notation : I find it makes code easier to read, having those `{}` ; and it makes sure you won't forget to add them the day they are needed.

Comment: ...and the backslash prevents PHP from parsing `${...}` as special expansion syntax. Although this could also be prevented with using single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The first curly bracket is responsible for the counting of the characters. `.{10}` means: 10 times any character.
The \${1} represents everything that is matched in the first pair of parantheses.
So, to paraphrase it: "Substitute the ten characters (`.{10}`) with the same 10 characters (`\${1}`) plus a space.